# SignalR ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have a problem receiving messages from an application because sometimes works but not always, and I have to F5 side to get back to work. Any ideas what could be?

correct messages:

> [19:15:27 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)] SignalR: Invoking question.SendMessage
>   jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8 [19:15:27 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)] SignalR: Invoked question.SendMessage
>   jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8 [19:15:27 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'newMessage' on hub 'question'.
>   gameController.js:19 2d856458-6874-44a9-a402-37ab6ca61cec: hello

incorrect messages(no answer):

> [19:15:51 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)] SignalR: Invoking question.SendMessage
>   jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8 [19:15:51 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)] SignalR: Invoked question.SendMessage

```
 $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();

    });

    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        alert("error: " + err);
    });

    angular.module('app').value('gameHub', $.connection.question);
```

In CTRL

```
 $scope.sendMessage = function () {
        gameHub.server.sendMessage($scope.message);

}

gameHub.client.newMessage = function onNewMessage(message) {
    $scope.messages.push({message: message});
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: Everything works if I go directly to the page where I have chat, if change my page and I will return, it stops working

Comment: You might go to packets level by using tools such as Wireshark.

Comment: When I debug program its woking (step into) but if I didn't some times my page don't get answer. Why ?

Comment: I think, that if you always use related  browser connectionId and client UserId to exchange data, you'll not have such problem.

Comment: You can get connectionId (it changed when user refresh page) like this: var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;

Answer (score 3):

As SignalR is for RealTime Application it will get you message as soon as the other person will send, meanwhile if you are on the other page where you don't have you hub connected then there can be two scenarios

1) If you've appended message through HTML or something then when you'll get back to same page (chat) then the messages will be removed due to page refresh.

-Solution

```
you can try saving messages to database so that when you get back you can 
retrieve you chat
```

2) The hub might be getting disconnected

```
so you should try using OnConnected(), OnDisconnected(), & On ReConnected() methods.
```

- P.S. signalR fires OnDisconnected() method when user Closes the Tab/Browser or when user refreshes the Page